# Python Dictionary index of a value

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, key, key-value

I am currently trying to get the index of a value from a dictionary and unsure what to try.

My dictionary is:

```
    midi2notes = {                                  
        'c':("0","12","24","36","48","60","72","84","96","108","120"),
        'des':("1","13","25","37","49","61","73","85","97","109","121"),
        'd':("2","14","26","38","50","62","74","86","98","110","122"),
        'ees':("3","15","27","39","51","63","75","87","99","111","123"),
        'e':("4","16","28","40","52","64","76","88","100","112","124"),
        'f':("5","17","29","41","53","65","77","89","101","113","125"),
        'ges':("6","18","30","42","54","66","78","90","102","114","126"),
        'g':("7","19","31","43","55","67","79","91","103","115","127"),
        'aes':("8","20","32","44","56","68","80","92","104","116"),
        'a':("9","21","33","45","57","69","81","93","105","117"),
        'bes':("10","22","34","46","58","70","82","94","106","118"),
        'b':("11","23","35","47","59","71","83","95","107","119")
    }
```

Example: I want to get the index of value-"60" from key- 'c'.  Which should be 5.  What would be the most efficient/quickest way to go about this.

Answer (score 7):

I would do:

```
midi2notes['c'].index('60')
```

This will raise an `ValueError` if the index isn't found, but if the numbers are usually in the tuple, it'll be hard to beat the optimized C backend.

```
>>> midi2notes = {                                  
...         'c':("0","12","24","36","48","60","72","84","96","108","120"),
...         'des':("1","13","25","37","49","61","73","85","97","109","121"),
...         'd':("2","14","26","38","50","62","74","86","98","110","122"),
...         'ees':("3","15","27","39","51","63","75","87","99","111","123"),
...         'e':("4","16","28","40","52","64","76","88","100","112","124"),
...         'f':("5","17","29","41","53","65","77","89","101","113","125"),
...         'ges':("6","18","30","42","54","66","78","90","102","114","126"),
...         'g':("7","19","31","43","55","67","79","91","103","115","127"),
...         'aes':("8","20","32","44","56","68","80","92","104","116"),
...         'a':("9","21","33","45","57","69","81","93","105","117"),
...         'bes':("10","22","34","46","58","70","82","94","106","118"),
...         'b':("11","23","35","47","59","71","83","95","107","119")
...     }
>>> midi2notes['c'].index('60')
5
>>> midi2notes['c'].index('180')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: tuple.index(x): x not in tuple
>>>
```

Comment: Also, just note that this won't work if there is another `"60"` in the tuple (which there isn't in this case). But still, +1 :).

Comment: @Haidro: In that case, there's no code that could possibly work, because "the index of `60`" is not a well-defined thing when there can be multiple `60`s…

Comment: @Haidro -- Sure, if it's not unique then the whole premise is off.  That said, algorithmically, you can do better if you `bisect` the tuple (since they all seem to be sorted).  For tuples of this size though, I doubt that will perform better.  **edit** bisecting won't work since they're not sorted because they're strings instead of integers.

Comment: And if this operation were being performed a gazillion (technical term) times, it might be worthwhile to make an index dict like `mi = {(k, v): i for k,vv in midi2notes.items() for i,v in enumerate(vv)}` or something.

Comment: @mgilson: I'm guessing `bisect` would actually be slower. Even though it's only O(log N) instead of O(N), with the OP's input data you're talking about 11 super-trivial C loops vs. 4 less-trivial loops…

Comment: @abarnert -- Agreed.  That's why I said "algorithmically you'd do better" and "for tuples of this size, I doubt that you will do better"

Comment: This is probably what I will be using.  The values in the dictionary are finite and will never change, there are no duplicates (ultimately it is just the numbers 0-127 mapped to different key's) so this will work perfectly with what I am trying to do.  Thank you, I am always amazed at how simple things are in Python, I tend to make it more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to do this often, instead of looking up the index each time, just create a `dict` that maps the values back to indices:

```
midi2notes_map = {key: {value: index for index, value in enumerate(tup)}
                  for key, tup in midi2notes.items()}
```

Then you can just do this:

```
midi2notes_map['c']['60']
```

Or, alternatively:

```
midi2notes_map = {(key, value): index
                  for key, tup in midi2notes.items()
                  for index, value in enumerate(tup)}

midi2notes_map['c', 60]
```

This should be on the order a 5x more efficient each time you do a lookup (since you just need to hash the key, instead of linearly searching a tuple of 10 items)… But of course building up the map takes some time, so if you're only doing a couple of lookups, it may not be worth it.

Of course you should make sure that the performance of this lookup really is relevant before worrying about it. (I'm guessing the slowest implementation you could come up with, using an explicit nested loop, would still be fast enough to play a MIDI sequence…) And, if it is, set up a test using `timeit` with your actual data and usage patterns to find out what's actually fastest.

Comment: @mgilson: Really, it depends on what the rest of his app looks like. If he might have another good use for `midi2notes_map['c']`, the first one is definitely better; if there's no such conceivable use, probably the second. (I think `hash(('c', 60))` and one lookup would go faster than the two simpler hashes and lookups… but then fitting a whole hash table into a cache line might make a difference too…)

Comment: This is a very useful and diverse way to do this, although it is slightly more than my app needs right now, if I extend it in the future(as I plan on), this will be immensely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

With `enumerate()`:

```
>>> for x,y in enumerate(midi2notes['c']):
...     if y == "60":
...         print x
... 
5
```

Comment: nice one. can be changed into a generator.